# catalysts in catalytic hydrogenation

Tags: catalysis

I am studying the very BASIC introduction of catalysis in general chemistry and encountered an example of a heterogeneous catalyst, which is catalytic hydrogenation of alkene into alkane using Pt/C or Pd/C, I have some questions:

1. why sometimes we need to use Pt, and sometimes we need to use Pd? Are there any differences in reactivity, or just purely depends on what is at hand?
2. I know the addition of activated carbon powder is to increase the surface area between reactants and catalyst. However, the carbon powder **isn't added all the time** when doing different heterogeneous catalysis reactions, why is it so if it is beneficial?
3. Bond dissociation energy of H2 = 436kJ/mol. But when H2 is adsorbed on the metal surface, the bond is broken. How come this simple step can break this strong bond? I suspect the metal-H bond formed is stronger than H-H bond, which means it is favorable, but I still have no idea where does the 436kJ/mol energy comes from.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Q3-Hydrogenation of Alkenes is an exothermic process.

Comment: Pt is rather more reactive than Pd as a catalyst so you might prefer to use Pd when there are other potentially reducible groups present.